# sending post request with curl getting 404

Tags: php, apache, curl

zendserver 2019.7
php 7.3
apache 2.4

In the test environment, I am sending JSON post requests through curl to my local server. When the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is less than e.g 1000 characters its scripts are executed and I am getting responses fine.

But the same script when I am increasing the length of the JSON array then I am getting a 404 error.

I have changed all the configurations like post_max_size etc but nothing working.

```json
$json_data = '{
  "Recon": [
      {
          "ItemNumber": "96",
          "StorageLocation": "L1",
          "Quantity": "2060.800",
          "UOM": "KG"
      },
      {
          "ItemNumber": "97",
          "StorageLocation": "L1",
          "Quantity": "2060.800",
          "UOM": "KG"
      },
      {
          "ItemNumber": "98",
          "StorageLocation": "L1",
          "Quantity": "2060.800",
          "UOM": "KG"
      },
      {
          "ItemNumber": "99",
          "StorageLocation": "L1",
          "Quantity": "2060.800",
          "UOM": "KG"
      },
      {
          "ItemNumber": "100",
          "StorageLocation": "L1",
          "Quantity": "2060.800",
          "UOM": "KG"
      },
      {
          "ItemNumber": "101",
          "StorageLocation": "L1",
          "Quantity": "2060.800",
          "UOM": "KG"
      },
      {
          "ItemNumber": "102",
          "StorageLocation": "L1",
          "Quantity": "2060.800",
          "UOM": "KG"
      },
      {
          "ItemNumber": "103",
          "StorageLocation": "L1",
          "Quantity": "2060.800",
          "UOM": "KG"
      },
      {
          "ItemNumber": "104",
          "StorageLocation": "L1",
          "Quantity": "2060.800",
          "UOM": "KG"
      },
      {
          "ItemNumber": "105",
          "StorageLocation": "L1",
          "Quantity": "2060.800",
          "UOM": "KG"
      },
      {
          "ItemNumber": "106",
          "StorageLocation": "L1",
          "Quantity": "2060.800",
          "UOM": "KG"
      },
      {
          "ItemNumber": "107",
          "StorageLocation": "L1",
          "Quantity": "2060.800",
          "UOM": "KG"
      },
      {
          "ItemNumber": "108",
          "StorageLocation": "L1",
          "Quantity": "2060.800",
          "UOM": "KG"
      }
  ]
}';

$url = 'http://ipaddress/projectname/recon.php';

$ch = curl_init($url);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: could you post your php code?

Comment: Thanks juan and ken please check i have updated the code

Comment: If its 404 then it means $url is incorrect. please check that.

Comment: Url is correct just when i am increasing the json_data getting 404 if data is less url is okay

Comment: Try changing your curl timeout setting e.g. `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);`

Comment: curl timeout change but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);`
you try to send a string.

php manuals says:

> CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value.

try this, your string as array with key named myjson:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['myjson'=>$json_data]);`

Comment: still not working but I forgot to mention that my application server is on localhost and i am access it through the public IP may be router configuration need to set for large data

Comment: Thanks for support and finally i track there was a firewall restriction which Network team resolve and it now working fine. Thanks again